# How to not set a key in object literal notation if the value of the key is undefined

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm creating a RPG character generator using Redux. In my reducer I want to be able to modify gear and keep track of these modifications. The modifications can have a rating, but do not necessarily have to have a rating.

So if the rating is undefined, I'd prefer to not record that. So is there a way to not add a key in object literal notation if the value is undefined?

gearName will be a string of the gear to be modified.

mod is an object which contains properties about the mod, like +rating fire resist or whatever.

rating is a number to represent the value of the modification.

```
const purchaseGear = (state, action) => {
  const { gearName, mod, rating } = action.parameter;

  switch (action.type) {
    case MOD_GEAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        [gearName]: {
          ...state[gearName],
          mods: {
            ...state[gearName].mods,
            [mod.name]: {
              ...mod,
              rating
            }
          },
          cost: mod.cost * (rating || 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any way to do that in the specification for [*Object initilazer*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer): "*It is a list of zero or more pairs of property keys and associated values, enclosed in curly brackets*".

Comment: What's the overall goal of this? Generally it is better to keep objects a consistent shape for performance. Changing whether the key exists based on the value will likely slow down your code.

Comment: A trick which works with `Object.assign` is `Object.assign({}, rating && {rating})`, taking advantage of the fact that `Object.assign` ignores null/false/undefined arguments.

Comment: I would like to mention making more reducers that operate on smaller *slices* of your application's state. These reducers can be combined into a root reducer using [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Axel Rauschmayer on 2ality.com](http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html#conditionally-adding-properties-inside-object-literals) proposes the following pattern:

```js
const cond = false;
const obj = {
    ...(cond ? {a: 1} : {}),
    b: 2,
};
    // {b: 2}
```

So in your case it would be something like

```js
...(rating !== undefined ? {rating: rating} : {})
```

Keep in mind that this pattern only works if the engine already supports the [Object rest/spread-proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread). It works in Chrome v58, but I haven't tested in on other platforms.

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you. And its also wonderfully elegant.